# High-energy scattering matrix a become wilson line

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, wilson-loop

I would like to ask why the scattering matrix $S^{ab}(x)=\left\langle gluon\: b|gluon\: a\right\rangle$ can be approximated for fast particle interacting with a traget field $A^{-}$ by wilson line $S^{ab}(x)=\left[P\exp\left\{ ig\int dx^{+}T_{c}A_{c}^{-}(x^{+},x_{\perp})\right\} \right]^{ab}$

Comment: I would like to ask moderators to get a permit to set a bounty on this question (today).

Comment: Wait, which thing is approximating what? Gluons aren't valid asymptotic states, no?

Comment: I agree that gluons aren't valid asymptotic states but that doesn't mean we can't define a scattering matrix for them.

Comment: Hi @Yair: You might want to include a reference to that statement in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to wave my hands wildly here, but I think the point is that you are treating the particle semi-classically, and the amplitude for going from point a to point b is equal to the 1-particle Feynman path integral, which is dominated by the classical action. The kinetic part contributes a simple phase, while the minimal coupling with the field $A$ contributes a phase that is equal to the path-ordered exponential you have written.